# Log Cocoapod dependancies and version in iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I'd like to log which Cocoapods and their related versions I'm using in a project but not sure how to do this. Is there a method available that I can use to write these values to a log file? I'm using Objective-C for this project but I can port from Swift if needed.

Comment: Aren't the dependencies in your `Podfile`?

Comment: yes, but with different versions of my app, and with the pods being updated on occasion, its convenient to know the versions of the pod files that are being used in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did this. First, go to  Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources and add the Podfile.lock (add other..)

Then I use this method to return the contents of the file:

```
     
-(NSString *)getPodfileLockContent  
{

        NSString* podfileLockContent = nil;

        NSError* error;
        NSURL* podfileLockURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Podfile" withExtension:@"lock"];

        _podfileLockContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:podfileLockURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
        if (podfileLockContent) {

            [NSLog(@"ERROR: failed to read Podfile.lock, make sure you have added it to the target in your project (this needs to be done manually at the moment). %@", error];

            return nil;
        }

    }
    return podfileLockContent;
}
```

This returns the full contents of the podfile.lock. You can just print this out or parse it for the values your require.

Comment: FYI - Keep in mind that anyone that downloads your app now has access to the Podfile.lock file since it is now embedded in your app. Probably not a big deal.

Comment: And the Podfile.lock file is not JSON. It's a text file, but not JSON.

Comment: oops...thanks, I'll correct that you are right. I've looked through the podfile.lock and don;t see anything sensitive myself but if anyone dangerous please let me know.